# JavaScript +c+ invalid link warning with jstree-3.3.7/jstree.min.js

Tags: jstree

I was running a validation checker on my site and it flagged this JavaScript file:

https://help-msa.publictalksoftware.co.uk/vendors/jstree-3.3.7/jstree.min.js

The actual error raised was:

> An error occurred for the request `"https://help-msa.publictalksoftware.co.uk/vendors/jstree-3.3.7/'+c+'"`. Failed Count: 3, Error: 0, Status: 500, Reason: Internal Server Error. This target will not be processed (tried 3 times). The original (root) target is "https://help-msa.publictalksoftware.co.uk/vendors/jstree-3.3.7/jstree.min.js".

I isolated the content in the file:

```
append('<link href="'+c+'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />')
```

I have checked my domain using FTP software and can't see this `+c+` location anywhere. Is this a bug or something?

Comment: This should most likely be a bug, jstree has no such file. The `jstree` library would just require the `jstree.min.js` and one or more css & image files.

Comment: @StephenS So, where do I direct this matter to for it to be resolved? The jstree vendor?

Comment: @StephenS Hang on - that is s string being added together isn't it? `'<link href="'` + `c` + `'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'`. So `c` must be some variable.

Comment: yep, should be some javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

I can see now that `c` is actualy a variable. It seems to be defined as:

`c=d+"/"+b+"/style.css"`

So maybe the HTML Validator I am using has not taken that into account.